# How do I fix the error when running ChatGPT in python?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-4

I need to get a working ChatGPT in python. I used the official documentation from the openal website and wrote this code:

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key='<my API is written here>')

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
    {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
  ]
)
```

After the launch, I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\1.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 275, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\chat\completions.py", line 663, in create
    return self._post(
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1200, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 889, in request
    return self._request(
  File "C:\Users\danuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 980, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.PermissionDeniedError: <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<style>body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
<script>
  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');
      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->


</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1 data-translate="block_headline">Sorry, you have been blocked</h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="unable_to_access">You are unable to access</span> api.openai.com</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-highlight">
        <div class="cf-wrapper">
          <div class="cf-screenshot-container cf-screenshot-full">
            
              <span class="cf-no-screenshot error"></span>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="blocked_why_headline">Why have I been blocked?</h2>

            <p data-translate="blocked_why_detail">This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="blocked_resolve_headline">What can I do to resolve this?</h2>

            <p data-translate="blocked_resolve_detail">You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->

      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">86264a8269155ab2</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">5.228.83.46</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have not found any information about this error. I've tried changing the version, writing different variations of the code, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It does not surprise me that changing the code does not help since the error page says that you are blocked, which means for some reason the OpenAI server refuses requests from your IP.

According to [this](https://community.openai.com/t/api-access-failed-showing-cloudflare-block-page/506015/12) this might have to do with using VPNs or making requests from a [country that is not supported](https://platform.openai.com/docs/supported-countries), and changing your IP helps.

Answer (score -1):

looks like your IP is either blocked or your country isn't supported.

You can try using vpn or proxy. Also do check your API usage.